# Rectangle drawing with time as x-axis python pylab

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I have tried this and got error:

```
pylab.Rectangle(height=2,width=1,xy=(df.index,df.Forecast))
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-539-f66a97b6403e> in <module>()
----> 1 pylab.Rectangle(height=2,width=1,xy=(df.index,df.color))

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    692         self._height = height
    693 
--> 694         self._x1 = self._x0 + self._width
    695         self._y1 = self._y0 + self._height
    696 

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py in __add__(self, other)
    652                 return self._add_delta(other)
    653             elif is_integer(other):
--> 654                 return self.shift(other)
    655             elif isinstance(other, (Index, datetime, np.datetime64)):
    656                 return self._add_datelike(other)

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py in shift(self, n, freq)
    780 
    781         if self.freq is None:
--> 782             raise ValueError("Cannot shift with no freq")
    783 
    784         start = self[0] + n * self.freq

ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq
```

The sample of the dataset is something like the following:

```
                    Forecast    color
Time                                                                
2018-07-24 03:50:00 1.168318    r
2018-07-24 03:49:00 1.168393    r
2018-07-24 03:48:00 1.168798    r
2018-07-24 03:47:00 1.169103    g
2018-07-24 03:46:00 1.168032    r
```

I want to show the rectangle with the color as mentioned in the `color` column of the dataframe.

Even there might time when I wanted to plot to different values during the same time one above the other. Kindly, let me know how I can achieve what I am thinking

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you attempt to achieve here. A rectangle is defined by a point (x,y) in space and a width and height. In addition you may specify a facecolor or edgecolor.

Comment: Respected Sir @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have tried something like that with it. As you can see in the code I have specified the height, width, xy coords too. But I get the following error. Please have a look at it and suggest me if you have anything other than what I tried or if there is any improvement required.

Comment: A point (x,y) needs to be defines as a tuple or list of two numbers, e.g. (2,3). Here you try to use something like `(pandas.Series, pandas.Series)`, which is not a point. Also a point cannot be (2,"r"), that is why I indeed have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Please pardon me. I have tried `df.Forecast` in the `y` axis. and I wanted to have the color from the `color` column for the respective rectangle. I guess I am clear. Please let me know if any other thing to know.

Comment: Forecast is a column with many values. For one rectangle you need one point, not many.

Comment: So does that mean that I need to loop the values and plot it. AM I right?